# MissingCsrfTokenException: Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found

Tags: java, spring-security, websocket, csrf, spring-websocket

I am reading the spring documentation: [Adding CSRF to Stomp Header](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-sameorigin-csrf)

And I try to add stom header to the connect event but I get the error on client:

```
>>> CONNECT
XSRF-TOKEN:f86232c1-e877-46e9-b4e6-7427c3d89940
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< ERROR
message:Failed to send message to ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]; nested exception is org.springframework.security.web.csrf.MissingCsrfTokenException\c Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.
content-length:0
```

client code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/webjars/js-cookie/js.cookie.js"></script>
```

---

```
var headers = {};
    var headerName = "XSRF-TOKEN";
    var token = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
    headers[headerName] = token;
    stompClient.connect(headers, function (frame) {....});
```

websocket security config:

```
@Configuration
    public class WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
        @Override
        protected void configureInbound(final MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
            // You can customize your authorization mapping here.
            messages.anyMessage().authenticated();
            messages.simpDestMatchers("/app/hello").authenticated()//.hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/user/queue/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/topic/greetings").authenticated();
        }

        // TODO: For test purpose (and simplicity) i disabled CSRF, but you should re-enable this and provide a CRSF endpoint.
        @Override
        protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
            return false; //! I do it especially
        }
    }
```

spring security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD = "rockandroll";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/index.html")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/sender.html")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/index.html")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/js/**", "/lib/**", "/images/**", "/css/**", "/index.html", "/","/*.css","/webjars/**", "/*.js").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/websocket").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(new AuthenticationProvider() {

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
                return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
            }

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = SECURE_ADMIN_PASSWORD.equals(token.getCredentials()) ?
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN") : null;

                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(token.getName(), token.getCredentials(), authorities);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Maybe my csrf token header name wrong?

### P.S.

[image: server side message]

Comment: are you sending the CSRF Cookie with your request? I get that error if I dont send the cookie. It has to have the proper domain in order for your browser to send it.

Comment: @Will M, How can I check it?

Comment: it depends on what you are using to send the request. If it is coming from a browser, thru a website, then you should use the developer tools for that browser. if you are making it through postman or some other tool, it should have a builtin way of seeing what your cookies are

Comment: I can't edit this post because it's mostly code and won't let me, if anyone else can, please replace the [Adding CSRF to Stomp Header](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-sameorigin-csrf) with this unbroken link.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was not in Spring Framework. After updating to Spring-Boot (2.5.0, war+Tomcat 9 implementation, OAuth2) I have got the same problem.

It works for me:

1. Step 1 (add Security configuration for Websockets - you need for disabling SCRF Websocket Protection)

   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageType;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.messaging.MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

   @Configuration
   public class SocketSecurityConfig
   extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

   ```
    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages
                .simpTypeMatchers(SimpMessageType.CONNECT, SimpMessageType.HEARTBEAT, SimpMessageType.UNSUBSCRIBE, SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT).permitAll()
                .anyMessage().permitAll()
                .simpDestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        ;
    }
   ```

   }
2. Step 2 (add Access to Websockets and Stomp in Web Security configuration):

   import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
   import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
   import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
   import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;

   @Slf4j
   @EnableWebSecurity
   @ComponentScan("com.example.your.project.package.name")
   @Configuration
   @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
   public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig
   extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   ```
    private static final String[] OPEN_URIS = {
            "/**/*.woff",
            "/**/*.woff2",
            "/**/*.ttf",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/login",
            "/login/*",
            "/login/*/**",
            "/resources/**",
            "/error",
            "/error/*",
            "/error/*/**",
            "/oauth2/authorization/**",
            "/**/*.png",
            "/**/*.css",
            "/**/*.js",
            "/style.css",
            "/favicon.ico",
            "/wicket",
            "/wicket/resource/",
            "/wicket/resource/*",
            "/wicket/resource/*/**",
            "/wicket/resources/**",
            "/wicket/resources/*/**",
            "/wicket/*",
            "/wicket/page/*",
            "/wicket/page/*/**",
            "/webjars",
            "/webjars/*",
            "/webjars/*/**",
            "/webservices/websocket/",
            "/webservices/websocket/*",
            "/webservices/websocket/*/**",
            "/webservices/websocketHandlerEndpoint",
            "/webservices/websocketHandlerEndpoint/*",
            "/webservices/websocketHandlerEndpoint/*/**"
    };

    /////---Here some Configuration (not showed)------------ /////


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize.antMatchers(OPEN_URIS).permitAll())
                // (Optional  : )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 ->
                                oauth2.permitAll() // <-- actually not real, but here must be code
                        //....`enter code here`..
                        //
                )
                //.....
                .logout()
        // ...
        ;
    }

    //another part of Configuration .....
   ```

   }

**Note:**
1)"/webservices/websocket/..." -is Stomp endpoint
2) "/webservices/websocketHandlerEndpoint..." -is Websocket handler endpoint